# ASP.NET Ajax Script Component

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I just trying to update the version of my .Net application 2.0 to 3.5 so in this case I got this error. I tried AjaxControllToolkit and it didn't work for me. Any suggestions for fix this error

[image]

I tried AjaxControlToolkit and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

In your aspx page,  include

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```